# non static method cannot be referenced from a static context, can't call the method below

Tags: java, arrays, methods

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FizzBuzz{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(fizzBuzz(15));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                results.add("fizz buzz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                results.add("buzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                results.add("fizz");
            } else {
                results.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I am trying to print out the FizzBuzz array. however, why I can't call the method below by the name here? could anyone help me out please? Appreciate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does every method in main class have to be static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117781/does-every-method-in-main-class-have-to-be-static)

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate an object first and then call the method on it. Something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FizzBuzz{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FizzBuzz obj = new FizzBuzz; //Create an instance
        System.out.println(obj.fizzBuzz(15)); //Call the mouthed through that
    }

    public ArrayList<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                results.add("fizz buzz");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                results.add("buzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                results.add("fizz");
            } else {
                results.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

An easier way would be to just change the `fizzbuzz()` method to static but that is not a good idea

Now you will get your desired output using either of the methods described above

```
[1, 2, fizz, 4, buzz, fizz, 7, 8, fizz, buzz, 11, fizz, 13, 14, fizz buzz]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around this problem is to just change your method to static:

```
public static ArrayList<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
    //...
```

If you call a method from the main method it must be static because the `main` method is `static`, and `static` methods can only reference `static` objects.

---

But the better practice is to make an instance of your class, then call the method through the instance of your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz();
    ArrayList<String> result = fb.fizzBuzz(15);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

That way you don't have to make the method `static`.

---

Either way you get the same output, but the second option is more professional, neater, and altogether a better practice.