# Error when running code as java application

Tags: selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SELintroduction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        //Invoking Browser
        //Chrome - ChromeDriver .exten-.Methods close get
        //Firefox- Firefoxdriver ->methods close get
        //safari SaariDrier ->methods close get
        //WebDriver close get
        //WebDriver methods + class methods
        
        //  chromedriver.exe->Chrome browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32.exe");
        
        
        //webdriver.chrome.driver->value of path
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://rahulshettyacademy.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

what is the wrong here coding shows error?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: the IDE probably doesn't like you running methods in main... create a class which contains these functions and instantiate it there.  Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117781/does-every-method-in-main-class-have-to-be-static

Comment: also if you do pass the "args" var into another class, be sure to try/catch that instantiation to check for propertyveto exception...