# Cannot pass random enum value to function in Java

Tags: java, parameters, static, parameter-passing

Cheers, I am pretty new to java and I and I have ran across a problem
I have three classes, all inheriting things between them. Starting I have a class A:

```
public class A{
    private int index;

    public A(int index) {
        System.out.println("Creating an instance of A");
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

then I have a sublass of A, class M which has a enum inside as:

```
public class M extends A{

    public enum Letter {
        A,B,C;
    }
    private Letter letter;

    public M(int index, Letter aLetter) {
        super(index);
        System.out.println("Creating an instance of M");
        this.letter = aLetter;
    }   
}
```

and finally a last class P , subclass of M:

```
public class P extends M {
    private T t;

    public enum T{
        o,
        a,
        t
    }

    public P(int index, Letter aLetter, T aT) {
        super(index,aLetter);
        System.out.println("Creating an instance of P");
        this.t = aT;
    }

}
```

What I want to do is create e.g. 3 objects of the class P, and pass on to them RANDOMLY a value of each of these enums. I thought of creating a function in the main class which would be kind of like:

```
Letter getRandLetter() {
    Random rand = new Rand();
    int pick = rand.nextInt(M.Letter.values().length);
    if (pick == 0) {
      return Letter.A;
    } else if (pick == 1) {
      return Letter.B;
    } else {
      return Letter.C;
    }
  }
```

my main looks like this:

```
int N = 3;
M[] new_m = new M[N]

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        new_m[i] = new P(i, getRandLetter(), getRandT());
      }
```

however I get this error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method` . What Can I do to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling what to do:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Your main method is static, and the methods called from it should be static as well. So your `getRandLetter()` and `getRandT()` methods should be static.

`getRandLetter()` should look like this:

```java
static Letter getRandLetter() {
    Random rand = new Rand();
    int pick = rand.nextInt(M.Letter.values().length);
    if (pick == 0) {
      return Letter.A;
    } else if (pick == 1) {
      return Letter.B;
    } else {
      return Letter.C;
    }
  }
```

And `getRandT()` should be static as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have one question. Could I define this function somewhere else to the code would be cleaner? Let's say as a member function of the enums? Or would that cause a problem? Thanks again =)

Comment: That's one way to do it but it throws you in a snake pit of static's. A better solution is described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117781/does-every-method-in-main-class-have-to-be-static It describes how to escape the static trap by instantiating a object of the class containing the main() function.